# Magento add configurable product to cart from order items

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to add a product to cart with selected option of a ordered product. 
As Example I have  ordered a configurable product where available options are **S,M,L**. I select **M** and order it. Now I want to pull this order and programmatically move to cart again. 
I try this in many different process but not success by me yet.  Please anyone suggest  to me how to do this?

Comment: You have to provide any code demonstrating your efforts to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supravat,
Please try to get option id of size of size using eav attibute the programically create an cart url

```
 <?php
$ConfigProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($cpid);
$GetAllowAttributes=$ConfigProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getConfigurableAttributes($ConfigProduct);

 foreach ($GetAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
               $attribute_code= $productAttribute->getAttributeCode();
               $attributeid=$productAttribute->getId();
               break;


 }
$attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code);
$options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
foreach($options as $option){
    // print_r($option) and find all the elements
    //echo $option["value"];
    //echo $option["label"];
    if($option["label"]==$youlabel){
        $opid=$option["value"];
         $cartUrl=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($ConfigProduct).'?super_attribute['.$attributeid.']='.$option["value"].'&qty=1';
         break;
    }
}
```